# Issue regarding showing pivot data in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

i am in situation where i need to form a complex sql to show calendar like interface with `datagridview in winform apps`. i have done the job writing code in form. now i want to form the calendar at database level with sql. this is my UI look like

[image]
now i have to generate the above output at database level with sql. here i am giving the below sql which is giving right data almost but still there is a small issue. first see the sql

```
DECLARE @MonthNo INT
DECLARE @Year INT

SET @MonthNo = 1
SET @Year = 2011

;WITH DataToPivot AS
(   SELECT  s.SpecialistID,
            s.Name, 
            DayNumber = DATEPART(DAY, h.EntryDate),
            HoursData = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h.EntryDate) IN (6, 7) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'S')
                            WHEN h.HoursData IS NULL THEN '8.00'
                            ELSE h.HoursData
                        END
    FROM    Specialists AS s
            LEFT JOIN HourSheet AS h
                ON h.SpecialistID = s.SpecialistID
                AND Month(h.EntryDate)= @MonthNo
                AND Year(h.EntryDate) = @Year
    WHERE   s.IsActive = 1 
    AND     s.IsSpecialist = 1 
    AND     s.IsExcluded = 0
)

select * from DataToPivot

SELECT  pvt.SpecialistID,
        pvt.Name,
        [1] = ISNULL(pvt.[1], '8.00'),
        [2] = ISNULL(pvt.[2], '8.00'),
        [3] = ISNULL(pvt.[3], '8.00'),
        [4] = ISNULL(pvt.[4], '8.00'),
        [5] = ISNULL(pvt.[5], '8.00'),
        [6] = ISNULL(pvt.[6], '8.00'),
        [7] = ISNULL(pvt.[7], '8.00'),
        [8] = ISNULL(pvt.[8], '8.00'),
        [9] = ISNULL(pvt.[9], '8.00'),
        [10] = ISNULL(pvt.[10], '8.00'),
        [11] = ISNULL(pvt.[11], '8.00'),
        [12] = ISNULL(pvt.[12], '8.00'),
        [13] = ISNULL(pvt.[13], '8.00'),
        [14] = ISNULL(pvt.[14], '8.00'),
        [15] = ISNULL(pvt.[15], '8.00'),
        [16] = ISNULL(pvt.[16], '8.00'),
        [17] = ISNULL(pvt.[17], '8.00'),
        [18] = ISNULL(pvt.[18], '8.00'),
        [19] = ISNULL(pvt.[19], '8.00'),
        [20] = ISNULL(pvt.[20], '8.00'),
        [21] = ISNULL(pvt.[21], '8.00'),
        [22] = ISNULL(pvt.[22], '8.00'),
        [23] = ISNULL(pvt.[23], '8.00'),
        [24] = ISNULL(pvt.[24], '8.00'),
        [25] = ISNULL(pvt.[25], '8.00'),
        [26] = ISNULL(pvt.[26], '8.00'),
        [27] = ISNULL(pvt.[27], '8.00'),
        [28] = ISNULL(pvt.[28], '8.00'),
        [29] = ISNULL(pvt.[29], '8.00'),
        [30] = ISNULL(pvt.[30], '8.00'),
        [31] = ISNULL(pvt.[31], '8.00')
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SpecialistID;
```

if `HoursData day` is null and if the day is `sunday or saturday` then i need to show `S` and if day is not `sunday or saturday` but HoursData is null then i have to show `8:00` else i need to show value stored in `HoursData`.

how to achieve it with `pivot sql`. anyone can help or suggest anything.

by any chance the second pivot query can be shorter?

thanks

### EDIT

table structure as follows

### HourSheet

```
SpecialistID INT
EntryDate    DATETIME
HoursData    decimal
```

### Specialist

```
SpecialistID    INT
Name            varchar(50)
```

### EDIT 1

first see my sql which is close what i want but still need some changes

```
DECLARE @MonthNo INT
DECLARE @Year INT

SET @MonthNo = 1
SET @Year = 2011

;WITH DataToPivot AS
(   SELECT  s.SpecialistID,
            s.Name, 
            DayNumber = DATEPART(DAY, h.EntryDate),
            HoursData = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h.EntryDate) IN (6, 7) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'S')
                            WHEN h.HoursData IS NULL THEN '8.00'
                            ELSE h.HoursData
                        END
    FROM    Specialists AS s
            LEFT JOIN HourSheet AS h
                ON h.SpecialistID = s.SpecialistID
                AND Month(h.EntryDate)= @MonthNo
                AND Year(h.EntryDate) = @Year
    WHERE   s.IsActive = 1 
    AND     s.IsSpecialist = 1 
    AND     s.IsExcluded = 0
)

SELECT  pvt.SpecialistID,
        pvt.Name,
        [1] = ISNULL(pvt.[1], '8.00'),
        [2] = ISNULL(pvt.[2], '8.00'),
        [3] = ISNULL(pvt.[3], '8.00'),
        [4] = ISNULL(pvt.[4], '8.00'),
        [5] = ISNULL(pvt.[5], '8.00'),
        [6] = ISNULL(pvt.[6], '8.00'),
        [7] = ISNULL(pvt.[7], '8.00'),
        [8] = ISNULL(pvt.[8], '8.00'),
        [9] = ISNULL(pvt.[9], '8.00'),
        [10] = ISNULL(pvt.[10], '8.00'),
        [11] = ISNULL(pvt.[11], '8.00'),
        [12] = ISNULL(pvt.[12], '8.00'),
        [13] = ISNULL(pvt.[13], '8.00'),
        [14] = ISNULL(pvt.[14], '8.00'),
        [15] = ISNULL(pvt.[15], '8.00'),
        [16] = ISNULL(pvt.[16], '8.00'),
        [17] = ISNULL(pvt.[17], '8.00'),
        [18] = ISNULL(pvt.[18], '8.00'),
        [19] = ISNULL(pvt.[19], '8.00'),
        [20] = ISNULL(pvt.[20], '8.00'),
        [21] = ISNULL(pvt.[21], '8.00'),
        [22] = ISNULL(pvt.[22], '8.00'),
        [23] = ISNULL(pvt.[23], '8.00'),
        [24] = ISNULL(pvt.[24], '8.00'),
        [25] = ISNULL(pvt.[25], '8.00'),
        [26] = ISNULL(pvt.[26], '8.00'),
        [27] = ISNULL(pvt.[27], '8.00'),
        [28] = ISNULL(pvt.[28], '8.00'),
        [29] = ISNULL(pvt.[29], '8.00'),
        [30] = ISNULL(pvt.[30], '8.00'),
        [31] = ISNULL(pvt.[31], '8.00')
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SpecialistID;
```

when i execute the above sql then output comes like
[image]

now the problem is see Sarah Rodham first column and second one is showing 8.00 which is sunday or saturday. so first i need to check if there is data exist in hoursheet table for the date 1/JAN/2011 then i will show that if no data found then i will check the date is related to sun or sat.....if yes then i will show 'S' if date is not sun or sat then i will show 8.00 which i am not being able to achieve by the above sql.

now tell me how can you help me. what else info i need to post here. thanks

### EDIT 2

```
DECLARE @Days AS INT
DECLARE @DateInput AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @DateInput = '01/01/2011'

SELECT @Days = DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,@DateInput),0)))
PRINT @Days

;WITH TotalDaysInMoth(MonthNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MonthNumber+1 
    FROM TotalDaysInMoth
    WHERE MonthNumber < @Days
)

select * from TotalDaysInMoth;
```

Comment: please provide structure of specialist and hoursheet table with some rows of test data...

Comment: i update my post with table structured you asked for. please have a look and answer if possible.

Comment: please add some sample data and expected output. A few rows shuld suffice...

Comment: One more point: which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
DECLARE @FirstOfMonth DATE={ts'2011-02-01 00:00:00'};

WITH DateBorders AS
(
    SELECT @FirstOfMonth AS FirstOfMonth
          ,DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@FirstOfMonth)) AS LastOfMonth 
)
,ThirtyOneNumbers(N) AS
(
        SELECT N FROM(VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
                            ,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
                            ,(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30)
                            ,(31))t(N)
)
,RunningDates AS
(
    SELECT N AS DayNumber
          ,DATEADD(DAY,N-1,DateBorders.FirstOfMonth) DayDate
    FROM ThirtyOneNumbers,DateBorders
    WHERE ThirtyOneNumbers.N<=DATEDIFF(DAY,DateBorders.FirstOfMonth,DateBorders.LastOfMonth) + 1
)
,RunningDatesExt AS
(
    SELECT RunningDates.*
          ,wd.WeekDayInx
    FROM RunningDates
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DayDate)) AS wd(WeekDayInx)
)
,HourSheetSum AS
(
    SELECT hs.SpecialistID
          ,hs.EntryDate
          ,SUM(hs.HoursData) AS SumHoursData
    FROM HourSheet AS hs
    GROUP BY hs.SpecialistID,hs.EntryDate
)
,DataToPivot AS
(
    SELECT s.SpecialistID,
           s.Name, 
           rde.DayNumber,

           CASE WHEN h.SumHoursData IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN rde.WeekDayInx IN(6,7) THEN 'S'
                                                  ELSE '8.00'  
                                             END
                ELSE CAST(h.SumHoursData AS VARCHAR(100)) END AS HoursData

    FROM RunningDatesExt AS rde
         CROSS JOIN Specialists AS s
         LEFT JOIN HourSheetSum AS h ON h.SpecialistID=s.SpecialistID AND rde.DayDate=h.EntryDate
)
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   MIN(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SpecialistID;
```

Comment: i update my post like what kind of output i am looking for. please see my edit and answer if possible. thanks for your time.

Comment: @Thomas, find a new approach... You must put your WHERE back to the query... Please vote up and/or mark as accepted if helpful, thx

Comment: can u come with new sql query if u understand what kind of output i need.

Comment: @Thomas, Look into my answer. THERE you'll find the new approach :-)

Comment: thanks a lot perfect. i update my post. so please see my Edit 2 section where i write sql to return no of days in month. u create one CTE called `ThirtyOneNumbers` where days are hard coded and for which i update my post with a sql which return no of days in month. so please see and tell me is it ok?

Comment: see the last query in your sql. there is DataToPivot where days are hard coded....can we make it small and days should not be hard coded. what we can do. i know there is one solution that is dynamic sql but other than dynamic sql how could we make it small and days should not be hard coded. need your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @Thomas, you got something wrong there... No need for your "TotalDaysInMonth", Look at my CTE "DateBorders". This is done there already. Look at my CTE "RunningNumbers". It will stop at the last day of a month. Look at the output of a "short" month. The last columns are NULL... Anyway, you think from the wrong side... Don't do any ugly tricks with dynamic SQL. Just use C# code logic, to set the visibility of the last four columns according to the month's day count. Please vote up, there's a lot of time in there... :-)